# Oracle - Compare sum() with a numeric value

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I'm having some troubles with some comparisons.
I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1 Project
Id - Budget

Table 2 Member
Id - Category - Hours 

Table 3 Costs
Category - Salary/hour
```

I need to get all projects that have spent more money than they could. To get the money spent i use a sum() but it gives me an invald identifier error

```
select p.id, sum(m.hours*c.salary)as spent, max(p.budget) from member m 
join project p on p.id=m.id
join costs c on m.category=c.category 
where spent>max(p.budget) 
group by p.id;
```

I can't find anything similar and I don't know how to compare those two columns.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `spent` alias in the `where` clause; column aliases are only valid in the order-by clause unless you use a subquery. You should also be checking with a `having` clause, not in the `where`:

```
select p.id, sum(m.hours*c.salary) as spent, max(p.budget)
from member m 
join project p on p.id=m.id
join costs c on m.category=c.category 
group by p.id
having sum(m.hours*c.salary) > max(p.budget);
```

Or if you don't want to repeat it, use an inline view:

```
select id, spent, budget
from (
  select p.id, sum(m.hours*c.salary) as spent, max(p.budget) as budget
  from member m 
  join project p on p.id=m.id
  join costs c on m.category=c.category 
  group by p.id
)
where spent > budget;
```

You don't really need the `max()` aggregate for budget, if `p.id` is unique anyway, you can include that in the group-by clause instead:

```
select id, spent, budget
from (
  select p.id, sum(m.hours*c.salary) as spent, budget
  from member m 
  join project p on p.id=m.id
  join costs c on m.category=c.category 
  group by p.id, p.budget
)
where spent > budget;
```